# Fixed table header with horizontal scroll bar in datatable

Tags: datatable, horizontal-scrolling, angular-datatables, fixed-header-tables

I have a dynamic angular-datatable something similar to this https://l-lin.github.io/angular-datatables/#/withFixedHeader, also table got horizontal scroll bar. Currently fixed header datatable [plugin](https://l-lin.github.io/angular-datatables/#/withFixedHeader) not supporting scroll. Any idea how to implement this ?

Answer (score -1):

Check the scroll event of datatable and initialize it in angular,

angular.element(document).on('init.dt', function() {
   document.querySelector('.dataTables_scrollBody').onscroll = function(e) {

// dtInstanceCallback 
// call the dtInstance again.

}
})
so, whenever a scroll event happens in angular datatable then it will recreate the table which in turn works as expected.

Note: This makes datatable too compatible with scroll events in angular way :)